# BufferedReader issue in IBM Application Scanner

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bluemix-app-scan

I am parsing a huge XML file using BufferedReader in my application and while scanning it through IBM Appscan (which is a mandate in our organisation) it is showing High Vulnerability of Denial of Service (DoS) attack (Issue type AppDOS). I have already tried BoundedBufferedReader to limit the number of characters while parsing to resolve the issue. However, I am still facing the same issue. 
Let me know if there is any solution or suggestion to fix it.

Comment: It works with a non-buffered Reader?

Comment: It is then impacting the performance of the application

Comment: Okay, as it works with a Reader, try to circument Appscan by a BufferedOutputStream, or other means like when a timeout is possible, or maybe a smaller buffer size.